# Getting my <div>'s to line up side by side instead of stacking

Tags: html, css

I have the following :

```
<div class = "employee">           
       <img class = 'pic' src = "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQfMDb1Qtu7gTDZTfnFR2XcPqrfkn27zeWASTBfczi-GGQAIKG_"/>           
        <div class = 'employeeDot'></div>
        <p class = 'employeeInfo'>
            First and Last<br>Phone Number<br>More information
        </p>            
    </div>
```

But when I enter more than one of these, they stack on top of each other. How do I get them to line up side by side?

I have tried floating and displaying block, inline, block-inline, etc but nothing seems to adjust their position.

Here is my CSS file:

```
.pic {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2
}

.employeeDot {
    background-color: maroon;
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 0 75px 75px 0;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    left: 75px;
    text-align: left;
}

.employeeInfo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 175px;
    top: 0px;
    color: black;
    z-index:1;
}

.employee {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Edit: 
Here is a link to my code, although it is not working as well on here. The Info block is supposed to toggle in and out with each click. But for now I am just trying to get them to line up correctly

http://jsfiddle.net/Taiwantimmy/RSMyd/

Comment: inline-block should be it (not block-inline:) , and white space:no wrap; on parent might help to force them stand on one line .

Comment: Your question is unclear, what do you mean by *but nothing seems to adjust their position*?

Comment: That no matter what I set for float or display, they stay stacked on each other

Comment: Please provide a live example as it will help us fix your problem in particular

Comment: @ZachSaucier, I added a link to jsfiddle, I hope that helps.

Comment: @TaiwanTimmy I don't understand. They're inline. If you want the text to be inline put them inside of individual spans...

Comment: I have two different <div>'s there each with it's own pic, employeeDot, and employeeInfo. Currently they are stacking on top of each other, but I would like them to sit side by side

I tried using span, but that didn't work either

Comment: @TaiwanTimmy They're positioned absolutely so one can be on top of the other. Remove that if you don't want it...

Comment: @ZachSaucier The .employee class is not positioned absolutely, so shouldn't the two .employee divs display on two different lines?

Comment: @TaiwanTimmy No. You need to [learn the basics](http://learnlayout.com/) of CSS positioning.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly - not sure why you are using the [**direct child selector `>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to prefix all your selectors, you may want to remove this (I see you've now removed this from your question).

To make all `.employee` blocks line up, [**you can use `display:inline-block`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values):

```
.employee {
    background-color: yellow;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

An alternative, would be to [**float them side by side (e.g `float:left`)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) though the float will need to be cleared.

Answer (score 2):

`DIV`s are block elements -- they expand to fill the width.

`SPAN`s are inline elements -- they contract to contain just their contents.

You want to use SPANs here.

Comment: What is inaccurate about it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that the .employee class had height and width of 0. 
As soon as I adjusted the class to the appropriate width and height the float and inline-block functions worked as expected